# random number generator without doing refresh

Tags: java, jsp

Hello 
I want to create a web page which can continually sending random value to data base without doing refresh .

For example

```
<html>
  <HEAD>
    <TITLE>HTML Title</TITLE>
  </HEAD>
  <BODY>

    <H3 ALIGN="CENTER">
      Ramdom number from 0 to 10 : 
      <FONT COLOR="RED">
        <%= (int) (Math.random() * 10) %>
      </FONT>
    </H3>
    <H4 ALIGN="CENTER">Refresh the page to see if the number changes...</H4>
  </BODY>
</HTML>
```

in which direction i should go either of using applets or something which can easily be adopted . Thanks

Comment: The use of uppercased HTML tags and deprecated attributes and tags indicates that you're learning HTML based on heavily outdated books/tutorials. I'd suggest to review your learning materials/sources.

Comment: @Balus understatement of the day. +1000 for extreme application of tact and diplomacy.

Comment: @Balus u r absolutely 100% right but useless for my question :)

Comment: What does "u r" mean? Sorry, I am not a 10 year old SMS kiddie. As to the uselessness, it was not an answer to your question, but just a comment on your question.

Comment: Ouch you are getting personal. Sorry if you have taken my words in wrong direction . comments can be on main question for random no generator instead of exploring Html tags. Anyway thanks for your suggestion and no hard feeling :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use JavaScript to do this. It's extremely simple.

```
window.onload = function ()
{
    var output = document.getElementById('foo');

    setInterval(function ()
    {
        output.innerHTML = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
    }, 1000);
};
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/c9t3T/

Based on the HTML in your example, you should probably take some time and start learning [CSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Css) as well.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to create a web page which can continually sending random value to data base without doing refresh .

I wonder why do you need view for this. You can do it using some scheduled job , explore `Quartz`

If still you want to do that.. go for [DWR](http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/index.html)

Comment: Thanks for your concern but u are setting my direction for difficult approach i guess !!!

Comment: @umar, your question was confusing I guess, the answer you accepted it has nothing to do with DB

Comment: Actually i am in the need of this sort of code http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/c9t3T/ now i am wondering to fix it for the DB in a easy way using app engine

Answer (score 1):

You could create a div in which is displayed the random value, and modifiy the value in the  div using javascript function.