# random number generator function conversion into jsp

Tags: java, jsp

I want some random no displaying on the web page and storing it into the database . 
 please guide me how i can implement the same [tutorial](http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/c9t3T/) in jsp for continuous value without refreshing

Comment: What do you mean by "continuous value without refreshing"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [random number generator without doing refresh](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6032170/random-number-generator-without-doing-refresh)

Comment: @Jon Skeet like the stated over http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/c9t3T/

Comment: Start learning Ajax. You can find here some kickoff examples to build further on: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112686/update-current-page-with-a-servlet

Comment: @umar: Okay, so that's periodically updating... I'm finding it hard to guess what you then want to store in the database...

Comment: My answer with that Q. already answers you. please re read it.

Comment: @Jon Skeet performing some test work on google app engine . creating some sensor type of data for it .

Comment: @umar: That's still *way* too vague. You're showing lots of numbers. Which one do you want to store in the database? And where do sensors come into play? Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: Possibly not accurate way but i have find this shortcut <%response.setIntHeader("Refresh",1); %>          <%= (int) (Math.random() * 10) %>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This guy should help: [java.lang.Math random()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random%28%29)

Comment: Thanks for your concern but it will only give random value for once . As i want to  get same result as done in javascript http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/c9t3T/ ie values are constantly changing